# Kendo UI for Angular. Custom template for filter menu

Tags: angular, user-interface, kendo-ui

Kendo UI for Angular has possibility to define custom filter menu for column filtering but it is pretty inconvenient. (you should write template in each row definition )
like this :

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ApplicationShortName" [width]="100" title="{{ 'LABEL_APPLICATIONSHORTNAME' | translate }}">
        <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate>
            <grid-filter-menu [column]="'ApplicationShortName'"
                              [instanceId]="instanceId"
                              (filterEvent)="filterChange($event)">
            </grid-filter-menu>
        </ng-template>
```

is there any other way to tell grid that this is template and use it for every column and not to write by hand in each of it?
it has some default template, I want to change it
thanks